# Drupal site moved, now accounts cannot be opened

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, migration, settings, account

First question posted, apologies if it's been answered, but I have been searching for hours and can not seem to find the answer.

I developed a new version of my site on a sub domain and then set it live by moving it up to the domain itself -- a Drupal 7 site.

Apart from a couple of glitches everything went smoothly, I changed the settings.php to point to the correct base url, changed .htaccess etc, all hunky dory.

The one thing that is not working is account creation, either by the user themselves or by admin. I have checked permissions, all OK. No errors in logs. The live site is forced to use the https protocal, reverted it back to http, no joy. I read somewhere that the metatab module sometimes causes issues, I disabled it, again no joy.

I have an action that sends users a bespoke welcome email when admins create their account... This was working perfectly under the sub domain.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, there are no errors in the logs either

Answer (score 0):

Got to the bottom of this, I had over ridden the form_submit hook for user registration. Odd how it worked before...

Fixed